# Problem when trying to set class to next element

Tags: javascript, frontend, gallery

I'm making a gallery in a modal window and when I try to set a class to the next element, it gives an error "Cannot read property 'classList' of null". How can I fix this?

```
HTML
<div class="card-page__imgs">
   <img id="1" href="assets/img/card-page-main-img.png" class="card-page__main-img gallery-img" 
   src="assets/img/card-page-main-img.png" alt="Изображение">
   <div class="card-page__img-group">
      <img id="2" src="assets/img/card-page-img1.png" class="card-page__second-img gallery-img next-img">
      <img id="3" src="assets/img/card-page-img2.png" class="card-page__second-img gallery-img">
      <img id="4" src="assets/img/card-page-img3.png" class="card-page__second-img gallery-img">
   </div>
</div>
```

```
JS
const galleryBtnPrev = document.querySelector('.gallery__btn_prev'),
    galleryBtnNext = document.querySelector('.gallery__btn_next'),
    galleryMainImg = document.querySelector('.gallery__main-img'),
    galleryImages = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-img');

const showNext = () => {
    const galleryImagesArr = Array.from(galleryImages);
    galleryImagesArr.forEach((el, i) => {
        //if(el.classList.contains('next'))
        const nextSrc = el.getAttribute('src');
        if(el.classList.contains('next-img')) {
            galleryMainImg.setAttribute('src', nextSrc);
            el.classList.remove('next-img');
            // el.classList.add('next-img');
            const nextElem =el.nextElementSibling;
            console.log(nextElem);
            nextElem.classList.add('next-img');
            return false;
        }
        // console.log(el, i);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do `const nextElem = el.nextElementSibling;` because you have converted the nodeList to an array so the `nextElementSibiling` property doesn't work, however you can iterate through a nodeList using the `forEach` anyway so if you remove the `const galleryImagesArr = Array.from(galleryImages);` and just use `galleryImages` in place of `galleryImagesArr` It will work

**EDIT**
The error was from trying to read next sibling at when at the end of the array so it was returning null instead of wrapping over to the start, fixed this with simple IF statement

Like this

```
const galleryBtnPrev = document.querySelector('.gallery__btn_prev'),
    galleryBtnNext = document.querySelector('.gallery__btn_next'),
    galleryMainImg = document.querySelector('.gallery__main-img'),
    galleryImages = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-img');

const showNext = () => {
    galleryImages.forEach((el, i) => {
        //if(el.classList.contains('next'))
        const nextSrc = el.getAttribute('src');
        if(el.classList.contains('next-img')) {
            //galleryMainImg.setAttribute('src', nextSrc);
            el.classList.remove('next-img');
            // el.classList.add('next-img');
            var nextElem = el.nextElementSibling
            if (nextElem === null) {
              nextElem = galleryImages[0]
            }
            nextElem.classList.add('next-img'); 
            return false;
        }
        // console.log(el, i);
    });
};
showNext()
```

Comment: Removed the conversion, as you said, it's still the same error